# Pairing of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Suppose we have a pairing i.e. a bilinear map $\phi : V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. There are many ways of getting a map $ \psi: V \rightarrow V^* $ two of which are $v\rightarrow \langle v,.\rangle $ and $v\rightarrow \langle .,v\rangle $. Which of these should be called a canonical map associated with the pairing ? If the pairing is symmetric to start with, these two ways are the same but not in the general case. Is there a standard convention followed in the literature which associates to each pairing a linear transformation from the vector space to its dual ?

Comment: I prfer to use "canonical map" only for those appearing in universal constructs. So for the direct product $V\times V$ we already have two distinct canonical maps, the two projections $V\times V\to V$ to the two factors, and neither of these is "more canonical" than the other. A similar situation arises here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of breaking your tie is by looking to your choice of convention for a sesquilinear complex-valued pairing $\Phi : H \times H \to \mathbb{C}$ (e.g., the inner product on a complex vector space), since taking the real part $\Re \Phi : H \times H \to \mathbb{R}$ is a fairly common source of real-valued pairings, at least in analysis:

1. Most pure mathematicians adhere to the convention that $\Phi$ sesquilinear is linear in the first argument (i.e., $\Phi(av_1+v_2,w) = a\Phi(v_1,w)+\Phi(v_2,w)$) and antilinear in the second argument (i.e., $\Phi(w,av_1+v_2) = \bar{a}\Phi(w,v_1)+\Phi(w,v_2)$); given this, the canonical map $H \to H^\ast$ is forced to be the antilinear map $v \mapsto \Phi( \cdot,v )$. Hence, consistency with this convention for complex-valued sesquilinear pairings might break the tie in favour of $v \mapsto \phi(\cdot,v)$ in the real case.
2. Mathematical physicists, on the other hand, adhere to the convention that $\Phi$ sesquilinear is linear in the *second* argument and antilinear in the first; given this, the canonical map $H \to H^\ast$ is forced to be the antilinear map $v \mapsto \Phi(v,\cdot)$. Hence, consistency with this convention might break the tie in favour of $v \mapsto \phi(v,\cdot)$ in the real case.

Of course, as Hagen von Eitzen points out in his comment, in the case of your real pairing, you really do have *two* canonical maps, so any tiebreaker is going to be entirely artificial, as above.